# Error: Infinite loop in Red Black tree because no if-statements qualify

Tags: c++

I got the template (which others on this website said worked) from here

[Is Red-Black tree balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531044/is-red-black-tree-balanced)

I really cannot see an issue with anything here. I've been looking at it for about 3 hours. The infinite loops is the main error here in the balancing method, and it is because it passes through each of the if statements without finding any matching qualities. Also, the error in the RBT that needs correcting is that there are 2 red nodes in a row.

Constructor

```
MovieTree:: MovieTree(){

    nil = new MovieNode;
    nil->isRed=false;

    root= nil;
    root->left=nil;
    root->right=nil;

}
```

Add method

```
void MovieTree::addMovieNode(int ranking, std::string title, int year, int quantity){

cout<<title<<" added."<<endl;

if(root == nil){

    root =new  MovieNode(ranking, title, year, quantity);
    root->isRed=false;
    root->left = nil;
    root->right = nil;
    root->parent = nil;
    int b = rbValid(root);
    cout<<b<<endl;
    return;
}



MovieNode *temp = root; //root
MovieNode* parent = nil; //parent


//node is node to add

while(temp != nil){//gets to bottom of tree

    parent = temp;//sets temp to parent of location for where node is added

    if(title < temp->title){
        temp=temp->left;
    }
    else{temp=temp->right;}
}

MovieNode *node;

if(title < parent->title){//adds to either left or right
    cout<<"added to left"<<endl;

    node = new MovieNode(ranking, title, year, quantity);
    node->left = nil;
    node->right = nil;
    node->parent = nil;

    node->isRed=true;

    parent->left = node;
    node->parent=parent;
}

else{
        cout<<"added to right"<<endl;

    node = new MovieNode(ranking, title, year, quantity);
    node->left = nil;
    node->right = nil;
    node->parent = nil;

    node->isRed=true;

    parent->right=node;

    node->parent=parent;
}
int a = rbValid(root);
cout<<a<<endl;
rbAddFixup(node);//seg fault is here

}
```

Balancing Method

```
void MovieTree::rbAddFixup(MovieNode * node ){

if(node->parent->isRed==true){
    cout<<"parent is red"<<endl;
}

while(node != root && node->parent->isRed==true){

    if(node->parent == node->parent->parent->left){//first event doesn't apply

        MovieNode *uncle = node->parent->parent->right;

        if(uncle ->isRed == true){

            node->parent->isRed=false;//begin rbcase1
            uncle->isRed=false;
            node->parent->parent->isRed=true;//end rbcase1
            node=node->parent->parent;

        }
        else{
            if(node == node->parent->right){

                node=node->parent;
                leftRotate(node);
                node->parent->isRed=false; //case3
                node->parent->parent->isRed=true;
                rightRotate(node->parent->parent);//end case3
            }
        }

    }else{


        MovieNode *uncle = node->parent->parent->left;

        if(uncle ->isRed == true){

            node->parent->isRed=false;
            uncle->isRed=false;
            node->parent->parent->isRed=true;
            node=node->parent->parent;

        }
        else{
//infinite loop happens here
            if(node == node->parent->left){

                node=node->parent;
                rightRotate(node);
                node->parent->isRed=false;
                node->parent->parent->isRed=true;
                leftRotate(node->parent->parent);
            }
        }

}

}
root->isRed=false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduction:

```
while(condition1)
{
    if(condition2)
    {
         statements
    } else {
         statement that doesn't affect condition1
         if (condition2)
         {
             statements
         } else {
             // infinite loop happens here
             if (condition3)
             {
                statements
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Problem:

You have a while loop that descends into a state where it cannot advance. Your comment locates the position pretty good. If `condition1` is true and `condition3` is false nothing happens ever so the code never stops.

I'm very sure the remaining case is `node == node->parent->right` but I have no certainty of being able to write it. red-black is not symmetric.

Comment: So how does the example code i linked work then? It only has the same cases as I do?